Why does kafka stream binder configuration merge across Multiple Binders in SCDF?
We have multiple binders declared in the application.yaml for function binding in our code. When running the actual application, we define spring.cloud.function.definition dynamically for unifying the codebase.
However, when executing each binding as shown below, we have identified an issue where the properties under spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.* for binder-a and binder-b are being merged, causing both consumers to not function correctly. Specifically, after the application starts, if we check the kafka's consumerConfig logs created during the initialization of the consumers for binder-a and binder-b, it shows that the declared values are merged, resulting in both Kafka consumers using the same configuration.
Could you please confirm whether this is intended behavior or if there is a mistake in the configuration?
spring:
  cloud:
    function.definition: function-a # or function-b      
    stream:
      default-binder: shofee-a
      bindings:
        function-a-in-0:
          destination: topic-from-broker-b
          binder: bingder-b
          group: ${spring.profiles.active}-function-a
        function-b-in-0:
          destination: topic-from-broker-a
          binder: binder-a
          group: ${spring.profiles.active}-function-b

...

spring.cloud.stream.binders:
  binder-a:
    type: kstream
    environment:
      spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
        brokers: a-broker.com:10992
        configuration.security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        configuration.ssl.truststore.type: PEM
      ... 
      
  binder-b:
    type: kstream
    environment:
      spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder:
        brokers: b-broker.com:10992      
        configuration.security.protocol: PLAINTEXT

Excerpt from consumerConfig logs:
ConsumerConfig values: 
  ... 
  bootstrap.servers = [a-broker.com:10992]
  ... 
  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
  ... 
  ssl.truststore.type = PEM
  ... 

As part of debugging to identify the root cause, we found that in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsBinderSupportAutoConfiguration#binderConfigurationProperties, it appears that the configuration properties are being merged when kafkaStreamsBinderConfigurationProperties are bound for each binder. However, we have not been able to find a solution.
We are using
- jdk 17
- spring-core / spring-context 6.2.1
- spring-cloud-stream 4.1.0

Thank you.
